# Ckeditor 5, force new paragraph, instead of merge on drop

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am creating some custom elements, which are designed to be dragged into ckeditor

```
activeHtml.addDragStartHandler(handler->{
    handler.setData("text/html",finalDragHtml);
});
```

But the point is that these dragged elements should be inserted below the block element(Typical a p) they get dragged into.

So if the user drag the content into an existing paragraph, the entire content(Which is a text paragraph) should be placed below the paragraph where the user dragged the content, instead of splitting the target paragraph in 2. Is this possible?

The only solution I got which almost works is to grab the paste event, then insert the content into the model, and then cancel the drag.

That works except that I can't get the model position where the content is dragged, so I end up inserting the content at the current cursor position, instead of where the user dragged it.